# Counting Array Returns One Digit Higher

Tags: php, arrays, count

I'm trying to count a php array.
I have my code successfully counting it, but the value is returning one digit higher than what my array is.

I have tried using -- when echoing my array, but that doesn't work.

Here is my code so far:

```
$quotes[0] = "Volvo";
$quotes[1] = "BMW";
$quotes[2] = "Toyota";

$quotesCount = count($quotes);
echo ($quotes[rand(0, 2)]);
echo $quotesCount--;
```

When it count's it returns "3" which makes sense because there are three items, but how do I subtract a number when it echos so that it reflects the the largest digit in the array?

Comment: `echo $quotesCount-1;`?

Comment: Classic case of over-thinking something. What Rhum said, just -1 from the variable.

Comment: Well hell that actually worked. I don't remember what site it was, but it said to add "--" to make it subtract by one digit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tried with the `echo $quotesCount--;` is almost doing what you want it to. What you missed though is how the `--` works. You can place it either infront of the variable or behind it - and that makes a difference.

To get the full version, read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

But the short version is that you could potentially do this:

```
echo --$quotesCount;
```

Which will show you the value you want.

However this is still not really true - you are confusing array keys with the count of elements in an array.

If your array had non-sequential keys (1,3,5) for example, that code would return 2 - which is certainly not the highest key.

You can get a nice stepping stone to the key itself by using http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php - then you can reference the actual key itself by its order in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_max($quotes) z this will return the highest key in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Hey" you should array_max($array) in this case.

***array_max* is an array function which returns the highest value of an array.**

That's it,
Keep Coding :)